# django in memory uploaded file has no attribute starts with

Tags: python, django, rest, curl

i'm coding up a rest api where i'm passing a python file. i'd like to take the python file, import a function from it and use it.

I can read in the file using this: `custom_file = request.FILES['custom']`. If I print out the type of this, I get `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>.` This is a python file called test.py.
`
I'd like to import a function from that file but I can't seem to do it properly. Here's what i'm trying:

```
        mod = import_module(custom_file)
        new_func = getattr(custom_file, file_name)
        df = new_func(json_file)
```

I think there's a confusion between what i'm supposed to be passing to import_module, it requires a string of the file, but i'm passing in the file as a request to my API. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried loading up the function without the request using the commands above (if i just have it in the same directory without the rest api) and it works. So I just need to figure out how to access the right information from the request call.

Answer (score 1):

Execute arbitrary code is usually a terrible idea as it would have full permissions.

That said, you first have to save the file into disk. I would create a temporary folder  there using `tempfile.mkdtemp` ([link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp)) and saving it there. Then import it as a module ([see this question for more info on how you do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)).

Comment: i did that by doing this: path = default_storage.save(tempfile.mkdtemp(), custom_file). When trying to import it as a module, i get The joined path (/var/folders/tk/jb99sz1j0qgdjc12c7yxln500000gn/T/tmpcdstz219) is located outside of the base path component